# Can a Harengon take a grappled creature with them when they use Rabbit Hop?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, grapple, racial-traits

If a [Harengon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/814914-harengon) character grapples a target and then uses Rabbit Hop, can they drag/carry the target with them? If they can, is the distance of the hop halved like regular movement would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Designer intent implies that you can't move a grappled creature with Rabbit Hop

The movement rule for grappling is (emphasis mine):

> ***Moving a Grappled Creature.*** When you **move**, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

"Movement" is actually defined by the rules, and it has a specific mechanic; it does not use the common dictionary definition. For example, *misty step* is not movement, even though it moves you from A to B. Movement is explained on PHB page 190, under **Movement and Position** (emphases mine):

> On your turn, you can move a distance **up to your speed**. You can use as much or as little of your speed as you like on your turn, following the rules here.
>
> Your movement can include jumping, climbing, and swimming. These different modes of movement can be combined with walking, or they can constitute your entire move. **However you’re moving, you deduct the distance of each part of your move from your speed** until it is used up or until you are done moving.

The characteristic of this move is that it *consumes your speed*. Even jumping does so when it is movement. With that in mind, let's look at Rabbit Hop:

> ***Rabbit Hop.*** As a bonus action, you can jump a number of feet equal to five times your proficiency bonus, without provoking opportunity attacks. You can use this trait only if your speed is greater than 0.

Rabbit Hop does not consume any of your speed. It also does not say it uses movement; compare it to the Dash action, which states "*When you take the Dash action, you gain extra movement for the current turn*".  Therefore, Rabbit Hop is not the kind of move that you can use to drag along a grappled creature.

---

P.S. The designers intended that Rabbit hop consumes no speed, as stated in Wizard's [Sage Advice column](https://dnd.wizards.com/sage-advice/creature-evolutions) (emphasis added):

> **When a harengon uses Rabbit Hop, does the trait’s jump expend movement?** The Rabbit Hop trait lets a harengon jump as a bonus action, and *that jump doesn’t consume any of the harengon’s normal movement*. That fact is why the trait has a limited number of uses between long rests. If you compare the wording of Rabbit Hop to the wording of the long and high jump rules in the Player’s Handbook, you’ll see that those rules explicitly expend movement, whereas Rabbit Hop doesn’t.

However, [community consensus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208654/do-the-sage-advice-columns-count-as-official-rulings) here is that because that was never made an official answer of the Sage Advice Compendium, it should be ignored for a pure rules-as-written interpretation.

In that case, Rabbit Hop would consume movement, and because of that you could move a grappled creature with it -- but you are limited by your speed in how far the hop can go.

Either way feels kind of unsatisfying; if your group feels that way too, the DM could overrule it, to allow both jumping without movement and dragging along grappled creatures.

Comment: Interesting, does this mean the hop also ignores difficult terrain and such?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson I would think so, as it is not movement. Even makes sense narratively, they are hopping iver it after all.

Comment: In general I would agree, although many difficult terrain effects are volumetric rather than just applying to the ground, e.g. *Storm Sphere*. And I don't think regular movement-using jumps allow one to ignore difficult terrain.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson if mechanics is insufficient to describe narrative reality, there's always a DM to make a ruling. I, for example, would allow jumping in the sphere without reducing distance, but ask for a STR save to jump in desired direction, otherwise it'd be random. But that's just me.

Comment: @Jack. I don't mind, go ahead. It means to say the dash action says it adds move, RH does not. So RH does not add any move, is not a move and drag needs a move.

Comment: This is probably right but in the most boring way, as a DM would you really not let the rabbit player jump more than the usual rules support?

Comment: @SeriousBri I think you have a good point.  RAW, the rabbit can't jump with the grappled creature, but as the DM I'd be inclined to consider it.

Comment: I feel it's worth pointing out that this stance sort of defeats itself; according to game rules regarding jumping, "Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement." RH specifically allows you to use your BA to **jump** up to 5x your proficiency modifier in distance- without making any kind of check or referencing your STR mod. --->While it does indeed play out as 'increased movement' at most tables, nowhere in the feature does it actually say that you can make the jump without consuming your movement...

Comment: @TheFallen0ne Maybe you are right. Its the same issue with the ring of jumping - unless you have enough speed to cover, as written you‘d be limited by your movement. It makes RH a lot weaker, and (inofficially by Sage Advice, the column) is not intended but your reasoning is sound - I‘ll upvote you. Btw, not using move is how BG3 does it, and that clearly can lead movement abuse, as shown in various speed runs. Having it consume speed is lamer, but safer.

Answer (score 1):

### This should work; jumping consumes movement unless a feature says otherwise.

> Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.

Rabbit Hop allows you to use your bonus action to **jump** a fixed distance (5x your proficiency modifier) without checking your STR score or provoking opportunity attacks.

Unlike a Tabaxi's Feline Agility, which provides actual extra speed, Rabbit Hop is an escape mechanic for close-quarters fighting that lets you escape potential op attacks and take advantage of elevated terrain. When you use the feature, it still consumes your movement, per jumping rules.

Comment: If RH consumes movement, how far can I hop with a speed of 5 (I am exceeding my carrying capacity) and a proficiency bonus of 2?

Comment: @Kirt up to 10 feet, capped by your movement speed; in this case, 5 feet, with the full 10 feet available if you took the dash action. (Boots of Striding and Springing would also give you your full jump and disregard your carry capacity.)